# printf tilde operator in c

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I know that the `~` operator is NOT, so it inverts the bits in a binary number

```
unsigned int a = ~0, b = ~7;
printf("%d\n",a);
printf("%d\n",b);
printf("%u\n",a);
printf("%u\n",b);
```

I guessed 0 will be 1 and 7 (0111) will be 8 (1000) but the output was

```
-1
-8
4294967295
4294967288
```

how did ~0 and ~7 become -1, and -8? also why is %u printing that long number?

Comment: This program exhibits undefined behavior, by using format specifier that doesn't match the type of the argument. `%d` expects an argument of type `int`, but you are passing `unsigned int`. The "long number" is an `unsigned int` value with all bits set to 1. The value `0` consists of 32 zero bits, so `~0` is 32 one bits.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik tried int and unsigned int but it prints same output.

Comment: `a` and `b` may be `unsigned int`, but `0` and `7` are `int`, so the code is negating signed integers before assigning the results to unsigned variables. But *undefined behavior* is still *undefined behavior*.

Comment: The `~` operator may set the most significant bit to a 1.  In 2's complement for signed integers, the most significant bit is used as the sign bit.  When the sign bit is a 1, the value is negative.

Comment: `7` is not `0111`, it's `00000000000000000000000000000111` (assuming a platform where `int` is 32 bits). That's why the inverse is a very large number - it has lots of one bits.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews but I set it as unsigned int. can it still be negative?

Comment: @RemyLebeau ohhh thank you I now get it

Comment: Use `x` --> `printf("%x\n",a);` for more insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `~` operator simply inverts all bits in a number.

On most modern compilers, `int` is 32 bits in size, and a *signed* `int` uses [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation.  Which means, among other things, that the high bit is reserved for the *sign*, and if that bit is 1 then the number is negative.

`0` and `7` are `int` literals.  Assuming the above, we get these results:

- `0` is bits `00000000000000000000000000000000b`
  = `0` when interpreted as either `signed int` or `unsigned int`
- `~0` is bits `11111111111111111111111111111111b`
  = `-1` when interpreted as `signed int`
  = `4294967285` when interpreted as `unsigned int`
- `7` is bits `00000000000000000000000000000111b`
  = `7` when interpreted as either `signed int` or `unsigned int`
- `~7` is bits `11111111111111111111111111111000b`
  = `-8` when interpreted as `signed int`
  = `4294967288` when interpreted as `unsigned int`

In your `printf()` statements, `%d` interprets its input as a `signed int`, and `%u` interprets as an `unsigned int`.  This is why you are seeing the results you get.

Answer (score 1):

The `~` operator inverts *all* bits of the integer   operand. So for example where `int` is 32-bit, 1 is 0x00000001 in hex and it's one's complement is 0xFFFFFFFE.  When interpreted as unsigned, that is 4 294 967 294, and as two's complement signed, -2.